# Stretched image on raspberry pi official DSI display using Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

Got the official Raspberry Pi DSI display today (Same display as mentioned in this article: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/09/raspberry-pi-now-has-a-60-7-inch-touchscreen-display/) I use Raspbian with NOOBS.

The screen did work out off the box, without having to use any third party drivers. However the image is slightly horizontally stretched. E.g. a circle looks like an egg.
I have tried every setting I could find relevant in the /boot/config.txt file without any luck. Have been searching around the internet for the last 3 hours, anyone have any idea what I could try to fix this issue?

The reported resolution is 800 x 480, and that is correct. So i guess it's a aspect ratio related problem.

Comment: FWIW I'm seeing the same thing on my R Pi using Windows 10 IoT. Here is my question specific to that (still no solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989762/screen-resolution-issues-with-win-10-iot-and-r-pi-official-7-touchscreen