# Screen resolution issues with Win 10 IoT and R Pi Official 7" touchscreen

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

The official Raspberry Pi 7" Touchscreen Display (https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/) works really well with Windows 10 IoT Core running on my Raspberry Pi 2 B since support was added back in an Insider Preview (display and touch are functional). Except for the screen resolution. It is *almost* right, but everything on the screen appears *slightly* stretched horizontally which gives the app UI a cheap feel. Most notable are circular shapes that are stretched horizontally into an ellipse shape.

I've messed around with values in the `config.txt` file, which claims to be using `800x480`, but no changes seem to have any effect on the screen. Is there any way to make the resolution fit the `800x480` dimensions of the screen better? Below is the `config.txt` I am using. Please look  closely; I am using the custom resolution that everyone suggests. What I'm referring to is a slight stretch in the screen, not a completely incorrect resolution.

```
# For more options and information see
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details
# GPU Firmware SHA256 checksum: 7CE2EF13CDD77F1782FFFF98533572503DF4B46765966CC7E18F6C6455B9623A
# kernel.img SHA256 checksum: 8E86F0927DEC464C0D81BBD0B3E7C3FB852FE621853CD4F4E6D38786FAB573E4
# kernel.img git commit ID: 107b92c0ce491ba1e4d0d7068355cafa9da34920

#
# Boot
#
init_uart_clock=16000000    # Set UART clock to 16Mhz
kernel_old=1                # Load kernel.img at physical memory address 0x0
safe_mode_gpio=8            # A temp firmware limitation workaround
max_usb_current=1           # Enable maximum usb current

#
# Memory
#
gpu_mem=32                  # Set VC to 32MB, ARM DRAM to (1008-32)MB
hdmi_force_hotplug=1        # Enable HDMI display even if it is not connected (640x480)

#
# Overclocking
#
core_freq=250               # Frequency of GPU processor core in MHz
force_turbo=1               # Disables dynamic frequency clocking, so that all frequencies and voltages stay high

#
# Video
#
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1  # Ignore the alpha channel for Windows.
framebuffer_swap=1          # Set the frame buffer to be Windows BGR compatible.
disable_overscan=1          # Disable overscan
hdmi_group=2                # Use VESA Display Mode Timing over CEA
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=800 480 60 6 0 0 0 # Add custom 800x480 resolution (group 2 mode 87)

# Rotate the screen and control panel 180
lcd_rotate=2
```

Comment: I sometimes get better resolution after rebooting rapsberry pi with IoT Core. However, I don't have the official 7" touchscreen at hand. I'm using a 22'' LCD screen.

Comment: I've rebooted many times with no change.

Comment: I think it may be an issue with the hardware aspect ratio.  See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=120710&p=817889

Comment: That does appear to be the problem. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @koopaking3 Great - I've now posted as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with the hardware.  There are multiple reports of the aspect ratio of this device being off by about 10%.

For example, see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=120710&p=817889